# How to install an existing web service made with C# Winforms in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

My boss created a Winforms project and a web service. He asked me to create the same project with ASP.NET Core MVC and add the same web service. I'm a newbie and I don't know how I can start to do that.

Comment: Same way; google for e.g. AutoRest, NSwag, WebApiClientGen..

Answer (score 0):

finaly i did it using this code
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel _login)
{

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type:application/json"); //Content-Type  
            client.Headers.Add("Accept:application/json");
            string result = 
 client.DownloadString("http://localhost/Services/...........................);
            var _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
            if(_result["d"]["Login"].Value == true)
            {
                Response.Cookies.Append("User", _login.Username);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
```